# Github-like "pull requests" without Github

Tags: git, code-reviews

I work as an analyst for a financial institution, which, due to data sensitivity, will not store any data in the cloud. However, I'm having some success getting my team to use Git for code management. I was wondering whether there was any way to implement Github-like pull requests in our own server. The specific feature I'm interested in is the ability to submit a changeset *for comments*, without actually having it merged into a given branch. I like the workflow of (1) submit changes, (2) have changes reviewed and commented on, and (3) either accept the commit or reject it. Can this be implemented (even better, can this be *easily* implemented) on our own servers?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[`git request-pull`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-request-pull) anyone?

> Summarizes the changes between two commits to the standard output, and includes the given URL in the generated summary...

This should do the trick...

Comment: Great, Now how do I approve that PR and merge it upstream?

Comment: You probably approve it by writing a positive email about it, and you merge it using the git merge command, and then you push your merge commit to wherever it needs to be.

Answer (score 4):

You can self host GitHub for a price, personally I think it is very expensive but it is available as an alternative if you just **love** GitHub.

Personally I went with Gitorious and had great success with it. Self hosting it and integrating the project/repository features with a typical Git Merge Request system, it works great for distributed and non-distributed teams.

Comment: I'm actually just looking for that single feature. Most other features - easy sharing of codebases, following & forking, fancy project stats, newsfeed (ha!) - aren't necessary for our projects.

Comment: Don't use the other features.  You do need a managed server for hosting your git repository anyway.  I actually recommended GitHub for Enterprise over other solutions such as Collabnet.  The most important need you would have is to make sure it ends up in the enterprise SCM (which is likely not github unless your bank is cool)

Answer (score 4):

There are many alternatives to github.com that include a pull request feature, including several that you can install on your own server, either for a fee or in accordance with a free licence. Free options include Gitorious, Phabricator and Gitlab CE. One option that you would have to pay for is GitHub Enterprise.

See:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_source_code_hosting_facilities
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forge_(software)